# Jquery datatables checkbox filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, filtering, html-table

I have been trying the datatables multi filtering API but this is not sufficient enough for my needs.
http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html

What I'd need is a checkbox filter so that I could tick both the Gecko and Trident Rendering Engines and get only those values from the datatable. Any idea if such a filter implementation exists out there? I've been trying the columnFilter add-on as well but no checkbox filter there.

Thanks in advance,
Jimmy

Comment: Yes, thanks, but I want it to be displayed in the filter toolbar along with the other stuff. I was just wondering if I wasn't missing a plugin doing that stuff. Otherwise I will certainly go on creating it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen this example?

http://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/checkbox.html

Uses this init code:

`$(document).ready( function () {
                $('#example').dataTable().columnFilter({aoColumns: [
                        { type: "checkbox", values: [ 'Gecko', 'Trident'] },{},{},{},{ type: "checkbox", values: [ 'A', 'C']  } ]});

} );`